# In scala, how to declare a nested class to be transient?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I have a utility object that contains an implicit conversion:

```
object Util {

  implicit class SparkView(sc: SparkContext) {

    def do(): Unit = sc.parallelize(1 to 10).foreach {
      doSomething()
    }
  }

  def doSomething(): Unit
}
```

it works out of the box:

```
val sc = new SparkContext()
sc.do()
```

However when I change the above Util implementation into something slightly different:

```
class Util {

  implicit class SparkView(sc: SparkContext) {

    def do(): Unit = sc.parallelize(1 to 10).foreach {
      doSomething()
    }
  }

  def doSomething(): Unit
}
case object Util extends Util
```

The same usage of it gives the following error:

```
> Task not serializable org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not
> serializable  at
> org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:340)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:330)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:156)
>  ...
> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
> my.package.Util$SparkView
> Serialization stack:
>   - object not serializable (class: my.package.Util$SparkView, value:
> my.package.Util$SparkView@4f03729f)
```

It turns out that in the second case, the function doSomething() is serialized and shipped with useless things (the actual function signature becomes `this.$outer.doSomething()`). An immediate fix would be to declare all instances of SparkView to be transient, such that it won't be serialized and shipped, and function doSomething can be read from the singleton Util from scratch. How should I implement this easily?

Answer (score 1):

Spark ClosureCleaner is not a reliable tool for serializing closures. 
Closure captures `this` together with all fields and then ClosureCleaner tries to nullify fields which are not used using some heuristics with no guaranties.

So just keep the scope small and code simple and hope that it will work.

Also you can't make `SparkView` transient since transiency is an attribute of a field, not an object.